# Can I make eclipse SWT UI to look like Eclipse plugin UI?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

I am adding some functionality to eclipse, as in Eclipse plugin

I have one item that is a check box selection (see image)

```
    final ListSelectionDialog dialog = new ListSelectionDialog(window.getShell(), list,
            ArrayContentProvider.getInstance(), new LabelProvider(), "");
    dialog.setTitle("Create Events");
    dialog.setHelpAvailable(false);
    dialog.setMessage("Potential events in code:");
    dialog.create();
    dialog.getOkButton().setText("Create");
    dialog.open();
```

and another item that has radio buttons in it (I could not find anything like `ListSelectionDialog`, for radio buttons

```
public void display(List<String> list){
    Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            Display display = Display.getDefault();
            Shell shell = new Shell(display);
            shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());
            shell.setText("Create Object");
            Label label = new Label(shell, SWT.NULL);
            label.setText("Entry point: ");
            for (String item: list){
                Button btn  = new Button(shell, SWT.RADIO);
                btn.setText(item);                    
            }
            Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NULL);
            composite.setLayout(new RowLayout());

            Button createButton = new Button(composite, SWT.PUSH);
            createButton.setText("Create");
            Button cancelButton = new Button(composite, SWT.PUSH);
            cancelButton.setText("Cancel");
            shell.setSize(400, 200);
            shell.open ();
            while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {
                if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
            }
            shell.dispose ();
                }
        });
}
```

As you can see the item that is based on SWT, looks out of place and not consistent with Eclipse's UI.
Is it possible to make it look like the other one?[image]

Comment: All Eclipse dialogs use SWT, usually also using JFace `Dialog` which provides a higher level interface but is still basically SWT. I am not clear which parts of  your dialog you are concerned about.

Comment: First, the top left corner icon is different
Second, the size of the window (I am forcing it to 400,200) but it is not ideal (like the auto detected size that the other one is having)
Third, the create and cancel buttons look different

In addition, I am assuming I need to add my own listeners? to the selected radio and to the cancel/create btns?

Comment: Use the JFace `Dialog`, you can use the same `getOKButton()` call to change the OK button text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the JFace `Dialog` which gives the standard look. Something like:

```
public class CreateDialog extends Dialog
{
  public CreateDialog(final Shell parentShell)
  {
    super(parentShell);
  }

  @Override
  protected void configureShell(final Shell newShell)
  {
    super.configureShell(newShell);

    newShell.setText("Create Object");
  }

  @Override
  protected void createButtonsForButtonBar(Composite parent)
  {
    createButton(parent, IDialogConstants.OK_ID, "Create", true);
    createButton(parent, IDialogConstants.CANCEL_ID, IDialogConstants.CANCEL_LABEL, false);
 }

  @Override
  protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent)
  {
    Composite body  = (Composite)super.createDialogArea(parent);

    String [] list = {"e", "e1"};

    Label label = new Label(body, SWT.NULL);
    label.setText("Entry point: ");

    for (String item: list) {
        Button btn = new Button(body, SWT.RADIO);
        btn.setText(item);
    }

    return body;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey greg, thank you very much for this answer, it does look great I do have some followups

a) can I pass a list in the CreateDialog constructor , so I won't have a hard coded list in createDialogArea?
b) why is shell final in the constructor ?
c) Do I need to add another method to this calls to listen to the OK_ID button, if I want to return the selected radio button?
d) who does createButtonsForButtonBar/createDialogArea/configureShell being invoked automatically? I don't see any call for them, so I am a bit confused how it is auto-magically creates the window

Comment: Yes you can pass the list to the constructor. The Shell is final because it isn't changed, I have Eclipse set to add final whenever possible and forgot to edit this one out before posting here. Override `okPressed` to handle the OK button press. The other methods are all overrides of code in the base `Dialog` and are called during the dialog `create`/`open` call.

Comment: One last follow up, since I am automatically creating the radio btn with a for loop 
```    for (String item: list) {
        Button btn = new Button(body, SWT.RADIO);
```

since I need to find out which radio was selected, should I just store all btns in a Button[] array , and when okPressed iterate over that list and call isSelected, or is there a better, and more correct way to do this in JFace?

Comment: There isn't really a better way.